# Elevate Zoom adjust zoom window for different sized imagery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying out [Elevate Zoom](https://github.com/elevateweb/elevatezoom) and I've got a slightl problem i need some help with.

Basically as you will see from the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/y3vMt/) i've setup, i am trying to find out if there is way to reinitialize the plugin when you click on a thumbnail or reset the data so that for taller images (the photo of the tower), the zoom window isn't using the dimension of the first image. (which i gather from what i can find out that it is doing)

Unfortunately i don't have the power to make the people using this format their images properly, so accounting for various heights of imagery is needed. Can it be done?

**My Code, based on the demo file for the moment**

```
<img style="border:1px solid #e8e8e6;" id="zoom_03" src="http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/radial/zoom/images/small/image3.png" 
data-zoom-image="http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/radial/zoom/images/large/image3.jpg"
width="411"  />

<div id="gallery_01">

<a  href="#" class="elevatezoom-gallery active" data-update="" data-image="images/large/image1.jpg" data-zoom-image="images/large/image1.jpg">
<img src="images/large/image1.jpg" width="100"  />
</a>

<a  href="#" class="elevatezoom-gallery" data-update="" data-image="images/large/image2.jpg" data-zoom-image="images/large/image2.jpg">
<img src="images/large/image2.jpg" width="100"  />
</a>

<a  href="#" class="elevatezoom-gallery" data-image="images/large/image3.jpg" data-zoom-image="images/large/image3.jpg">
<img src="images/large/image3.jpg" width="100"  />
</a>

<a  href="#" class="elevatezoom-gallery" data-update="" data-image="images/large/image1.jpg" data-zoom-image="images/large/image1.jpg">
<img src="images/large/image1.jpg" width="100"  />
</a>

<a  href="#" class="elevatezoom-gallery" data-update="" data-image="images/large/image5.jpg" data-zoom-image="images/large/image5.jpg">
<img src="images/large/image5.jpg" width="100"  />
</a>

</div>
```

**The jQuery**

```
$("#zoom_03").elevateZoom({gallery:'gallery_01', cursor: 'crosshair', galleryActiveClass: "active", zoomType: "inner" }); 


var image = $('#gallery_01 a');
var zoomConfig = {  };
var zoomActive = false;

image.on('click', function(){

        $.removeData(image, 'elevateZoom');//remove zoom instance from image

        image.elevateZoom(zoomConfig);//initialise zoom

});
```

**Side note**

You might notice that I've made all the references to the images to the large file path, this is because in the way i need to use this plugin, the user will only be uploading a medium resolution file.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you asked for but a simple solution to remove zoom is by removing element data `elevateZoom` for the main image and destroy `.zoomContainer` elements. After updating zoom image element data you can re-instantiate **elementZoom**. However, if you want to keep the same image height for zoomContainer images you should consider having server-side image resizer and render them.

Here's a solution that I came up with:

```
var zoomConfig = {cursor: 'crosshair', zoomType: "inner" }; 
var image = $('#gallery_01 a');
var zoomImage = $('img#zoom_03');

zoomImage.elevateZoom(zoomConfig);//initialise zoom

image.on('click', function(){
    // Remove old instance od EZ
    $('.zoomContainer').remove();
    zoomImage.removeData('elevateZoom');
    // Update source for images
    zoomImage.attr('src', $(this).data('image'));
    zoomImage.data('zoom-image', $(this).data('zoom-image'));
    // Reinitialize EZ
    zoomImage.elevateZoom(zoomConfig);
});
```

**P.S.** Since you proposed using Click event, you can see I removed elavateZoom gallery functionality because it does pretty much a same thing if not used together with fancybox.

Comment: I just stuck for this about 2 days and finally got the answer. (+1 Thanks)

Comment: Thank you @Eglis—forgot I never wrote that all that time ago !

Comment: Thank you, that works great. I was using swaptheimage along with images with varying height, and that wasn't working well at all. This fixed my problem.

Comment: For others who may find this answer, you should also remove the zoomImage data, like this:  img.removeData('zoomImage');  See here:  [link](https://github.com/elevateweb/elevatezoom/issues/8)

Comment: Sweeeeeeeeet :D

Answer (score 7):

Use the built in gallery function and set the height of zoomContainer at every image change.

```
$("#gallery_01 a").click(function() {
    var myVar = setInterval(function(){ // wait for fading

        var height = $("#zoom_03").css("height");
        $(".zoomContainer").css("height", height);
        $(".zoomContainer .zoomWindow").css("height", height);

        clearInterval(myVar);
    }, 100);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If I tryly understand problem: width and height in zoom area must not changes after clicking on small images.
If so,

```
 imageCrossfade: false,
```

worked for me - image in zoom area preserve dimensions as I set for #zoom_03 in stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Fülöp Gábors excellent answer, you can also set widths to get complete dimension resizing.  This worked for me.

```
$("#gallery_01 a").click(function() {
            var myVar = setInterval(function(){ // wait for fading

                var height = $(".zoom_01").css("height");
                var width = $(".zoom_01").css("width");
                $(".zoomContainer").css("height", height);
                $(".zoomContainer").css("width", width);
                $(".zoomContainer .zoomWindow").css("height", height);
                $(".zoomContainer .zoomWindow").css("width", width);

                clearInterval(myVar);
            }, 100);
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change DOM attributes directly like this:

```
$('#zoomImage').attr('src', NEW_SMALL_URL)
$('.zoomWindow')[0].style.backgroundImage = ['url(', NEW_BIG_URL, ')'].join('')
```

Answer (score 0):

i have some alternative plugins for your needs, if you need read here.

http://kvcodes.com/2014/02/jquery-plugins-for-containerdiv-zoom/

Answer (score 0):

I found beautiful solution! Add this option to your config: `constrainType: 'width'`

```
image.elevateZoom({constrainType: 'width'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometime setInteval doesn't work. so I change code based on @Gábor. this worked for me.

`$("#gallery_01 a").click(function() {
    $(#zoom_03).on("load",function() {
        var height = $("#zoom_03").css("height");
        $(".zoomContainer").css("height", height);
        $(".zoomContainer .zoomWindow").css("height", height);
    });
});`

Answer (score 0):

I'm using lightSlider image gallery to trigger elevateZoom, only on the currently active slide, might be useful for this scenario too:

```
$('#image-gallery').lightSlider({

onSliderLoad: function() {
    $('#image-gallery').removeClass('cS-hidden');
    $('.lslide.active img').elevateZoom();  
},
onBeforeSlide: function () {
    $('.zoomContainer').remove();
    $('.lslide.active img').removeData('elevateZoom');
},
onAfterSlide: function () {
    generateZoomOnImage($(currentlyVisibleSliderImageSelector));
    $('.lslide.active img').elevateZoom();
}

});
```

Works perfectly and avoids the "elevateZoom triggers zoom on hidden images"-bug!

Comment: And dear Stackoverflow people, after 7 years it's still not possible to move entire blocks of code 1 tab...

Answer (score 0):

*For those who are using #zoom_03 or something similar*

**Size of output** image box can be limited after **gallery is clicked** using the following code.

```js
$("#zoom_03").elevateZoom({constrainType:"height", constrainSize:274})
```

*FROM ElevateZoom offical documentation:* 
[Image Constrain](http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom/examples#zoom-constrain)